# Add some fields from PyTable to Pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytables

I have a Pytable, with 12 columns. I would like to create a Pandas dataFrame including only some of them, for processing.

The PyTable is quite long, it has around 8-10 millions of rows.

I have tried so, but for some reason the process seems to be extremely slow.

I would appreciate any help.

Here it is my try:

```
import tables as t
import pandas as pd

cols = ['sheet','channel','ChipID','V','I']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

with t.open_file(talble, 'r') as pytable:
    tab = pytable.get_node('/test_data')
    index = 0
    for row in tab.where("(testResult == 1)"):
        df.loc[index] = [row['sheet'], row['channel'], row['AD0'], row['AD1']]
        index+=1
```

Note that I am only interesteed in 4 columns for my dataFrame, however the PyTable has more than 10 columns.

Comment: Why not just use the iterator from the `tab.where` statement into the constructor of a dataframe? Then just drop the columns you don't want at the end. Iterating and adding rows to a dataframe one at a time is not the way to go.

Comment: I thought about that before....but the concern about the size of the dataFrame and the `MemoryError` made me go for the iterating solution....what do you think about that?

Comment: I'd still use the iterator slurped into the dataframe construction.  If size is a concern, I'd break up the query against the table so it was chunked.  Do you plan on working with these 8mm rows in memory once you have a dataframe?